# How can i get a signed xml using azure logic apps

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-logic-apps

i was searching for an idea how can i sign a XML using a self signed certificate on logic apps. maybe using a function app? is there any way to get a signed xml using logic apps?

Answer (score 0):

There are no built in tools for signing Xml in Logic Apps, other than just .Net in general.

The reason is this is not a widely used function.  Do you have to use signed Xml?  Is AS2 an option?

Comment: Yeah, i have to use signed xml. the scenario is: i have a soap service, this service expects a string parameter that is a signed xml. i was trying to consume this service from a logic app. but i have to previusly sign the xml. So, AS2 is not an option rigth now